# After opening Task.Factory.StartNew in second time all my UI freezing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, task

I have function that received List of files and do work in single/separate threads:

```
public void DoWork(params...)
{
    _filesInProcess = 0;
    _filesFinished = 0;
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_indexedSource,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
                 if (OnFinishWorkEventHandler != null)
                     OnFinishWorkEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

I added the option to run this command in loops, from the main form after this function finished and if i need another loop i call to this function another time but in the second time this freeze all my UI and i cannot find out why

This is how i call to my function:

```
private void StartJob()
{
    string[] files = GetlFiles().ToArray();
    Job job = new Job(files);
    timerStatus.Enabled = true;
    job.OnStartPlayEventHandler += job_OnStartPlayEventHandler;
    job.OnFinishPlayEventHandler += job_OnFinishPlayEventHandler;
    job.OnFinishWorkEventHandler += job_OnFinishWorkEventHandler;
    job.StartTimerEventHandler += job_StartTimerEventHandler;
    job.StopTimerEventHandler += job_StopTimerEventHandler;
    job.DoWork(
                NetworkAdapter.SelectedAdapter.PacketDevice,
                ReadSpeed(),
                PlayOption.Regular,
                ChecksumFixer.FixBadChecksum,
                ReadParallelThreads(PlayState.Single),
                Iteration.Loops
            );
}
```

After this operation finished:

```
private void job_OnFinishWorkEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Job job = sender as Job;
    job.OnStartPlayEventHandler -= job_OnStartPlayEventHandler;
    job.OnFinishPlayEventHandler -= job_OnFinishPlayEventHandler;
    job.OnFinishWorkEventHandler -= job_OnFinishWorkEventHandler;
    job.StartTimerEventHandler -= job_StartTimerEventHandler;
    job.StopTimerEventHandler -= job_StopTimerEventHandler;
    Iteration.LoopFinished++;

    if (Iteration.LoopFinished < Iteration.Loops) // In case i want another loop
        StartJob();
    else
    {
        UnlockButtonsAfterPlay();
        UnlockContextMenuAfterPlay();
    }
}
```

And as i mention all stuck in second iteration

Comment: Its more than likely that you need to include your `//Do work` into your question, as it stands, there doesnt seem to be anything involved that would affect the gui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Task.Factory.StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). It uses `TaskScheduler.Current` as opposed to `TaskScheduler.Default`.

In your case `OnFinishWorkEventHandler` is fired from `ContinueWith` which is running in UI thread by `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. So at that point `TaskScheduler.Current` is UIScheduler and not `TaskScheduler.Default`(threadpool scheduler).
That's why your second task is scheduled in UI Thread which causes UI to freeze.

To fix this use `Task.Run` which always points to `TaskScheduler.Default`. `Task.Run` is new in .net 4.5, if you're in .net 4.0 you can create your `TaskFactory` with default parameters and you can use that.

```
private static readonly TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Then use

```
factory.StartNew(...);
```

If you're just going to use it only once you don't need to create a factory instance yourself, just specifying `TaskScheduler` explicitly will be fine.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
   //Your code here
}, _tokenSource.Token,
   TaskCreationOptions.None,
   TaskScheduler.Default)//Note TaskScheduler.Default here
.ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {
            //finish...
             if (OnFinishWorkEventHandler != null)
                 OnFinishWorkEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Task.Run instead of what ? i need to change something ?

Comment: `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: I suppose you're in .net 4.0, follow the workaround in my answer for .net 4.0

Comment: Can you explain me please how to use this fix ? (I am new developer...)